# run script via context menu

Tags: nautilus

Nautilus has this setting to either 'run' or 'view' executable text files (or 'ask').

How can I keep the 'run' context menu entry for the files in question when the Nautilus setting is set to 'view'? (so basically having both options available right in the context menu)

Answer (score 1):

Well at first I looked into nautilus-python as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414436/how-to-edit-the-context-menus-of-nautilus-file-manager). However the sparse documentation left me unsatisfied with being unable figure out how to determine position within the context menu and setting a context (file/mime type).

I ended up with going with a custom script as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21953/how-do-i-customize-the-context-menu-in-nautilus?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Creating this file:

~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/Run

```
#!/bin/sh
eval "./$1"
```

Make it executable with `chmod +x ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/Run`

Result:
[image]

I'm sure you know how to improve this so please comment!