# Disable Dropbox integration with GNOME Files (without disabling Dropbox sync)?

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, dropbox

I just installed Dropbox on Ubuntu 18.04. It decided that I would like having a menu item on Files (Nautilus) to move things to Dropbox (I don't).

[image]

So how can I disable this integration (remove the menu item) without disabling Dropbox sync?

Comment: I use Dropbox all the time and I can't be certain what you mean by a menu item on Nautilus. Perhaps you could edit your question to show a graphic of what you mean.

Comment: @Graham For some reason I can't take a screen shot with a context menu. What I mean is that if you right click on a file in Nautilus, I have a "Dropbox" item in the context menu that I don't want.

Comment: You can do that with Shutter... Are you sure that it is not just a symlink or a local network share accidentally created?

Comment: I have added the screenshot for you. I don't see a way of removing it (without removing Dropbox which you don't want to do) but you could disable Dropbox by opening a terminal and typing dropbox stop (and dropbox start to start it off again)

Comment: @Graham Thanks!

Comment: I did a little digging and got this so far: https://askubuntu.com/questions/878961/removing-the-move-to-dropbox-context-menu-option-thunar-16-04

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 16.04 you can remove the context sensitive menu option for Dropbox with this:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-3.0/libnautilus-dropbox.so{,.bak}
```

A backup is created in case you wish to revert (for example too much functionality is removed).

Next close Nautilus and reopen it:

```
nautilus -q
nautilus
```

---

In [Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/414443/307523) the directory name has changed to `/usr/share/nautilus-share/interfaces` but I haven't got around to testing 18.04, 19.04 or 19.10 yet.

---

In Ubuntu 22.10 the directory name has changed to:

```bash
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nautilus/extensions-4
```

Comment: Did you mean `/usr/share/nautilus-share/interfaces/`?

Comment: @PabloBianchi I checked the link and the author did type it that way.

Comment: It seems a typo..

Comment: Neither of these paths exist in Ubuntu 22.10 and the latest version of Dropbox

Comment: @Flimm Thank you for sharing. I've updated the answer with your comment.

Comment: @PabloBianchi Indeed. I've edited the answer. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Some packages of Dropbox for Ubuntu has additional extensions, be aware to rename extension-2.0

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-2.0/libnautilus-dropbox.so /usr/lib/nautilus/extensions-2.0/libnautilus-dropbox.so.bak
```

I have not checked if it's necessary, but take it into account.

Comment: This path doesn't exist on Ubuntu 22.10 and the latest version of Dropbox